# Does cache expire each time a dyno spins down regardless of expiry time?

Tags: heroku, memcached

On Heroku's free app tier, when the dyno idles does all the cache expire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the ephemeral file store, any cache written to memory or disk is likely to be cleared on idle, or when the dyno cycles. Dynos cycle approximately every 24 hours. Even with production apps (2 or more dynos, production level database), each dyno is isolated, so using disk or memory wouldn't function correctly anyway.

You should use an external backing service for your caching:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcachier
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and reference links.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your precise question: nothing is done regarding caching in particular, but if you have anything stored in the dyno's memory or filesystem, that's destroyed.

Specifically, the term "idling" can be a misleading; idled dynos are actually completely destroyed, and unidling actually means booting up a fresh new dyno.